# Login Screen is Showing on External Monitor

Tags: xorg, manjaro, plasma

I recently installed Manjaro Plasma. I have ASUS with Nvidia GTX 1650 Ti.

This is my `lspci` setting:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 109f
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Picasso
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

I created and changed xorg.conf file so it look like this:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.59

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen1" 0 0
    Screen      1   "Screen0" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "HPN HP 24fw"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 86.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "Primary" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 86.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "Primary" "true"        
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "01:00.0"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1650"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "amdgpu"
    BusID          "05:00.0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I tired to add Option Primary true on laprop screen but it hasnt chamged anythig so i suppose this line is unecesarry.
Also default xorg.conf file has everything inside but Screen1, Monitor1 and Device 1 and back then only worked External Monitor so I added those Screen1, Monitor1 and Device1 so the laptop screen would be workig too..

Now Everything is working fine when the external monitor is on. Also when I login and the disable the second monitor. But the problem is  that the login screen is  showing on external monitor and the laptops display only shows after login. So when I have no external monitor connected. I cant log into linux.

Comment: Did you use a tool to create and change `xorg.conf`? Does it allow you to select which is the primary monitor? Maybe you have to change the `Option         "Primary" "false"` or `... "true"` lines in the `"Monitor"` sections. Please, don't answer in comments, [edit] your question to add information or clarification.

Comment: Same problem there when the 2nd monitor is enabled (I'm using lightdm) if I move the (hidden) mouse pointer to the primary monitor it show the login there, but I'm looking for a solution to enable/disable the second monitor config depending on the monitor signal.

Comment: @Alex i was thinking about the same solution but i domt have time to do it.. if you'll get it running, please answer this thread

Comment: @PatrikBašo I'm currently looking for a way to detect the signal status, I'll let you know.

Comment: @PatrikBašo I have not found any way to check if a monitor signal is on or off, not with my setup, so I always switch the secondary off at the login screen, and restore the secondary status by reading it from a persistent file when I log in with the user (I use a script to switch it on/off that stores the new state)